# Jenkins pipeline/docker :Jenkins does not seem to be running inside a container

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to execute the sample of code found in Jenkins Pipeline here : https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/

```
node {
/* Requires the Docker Pipeline plugin to be installed */
    docker.image('maven:3-alpine').inside('-v $HOME/.m2:/root/.m2') {
        stage('Build') {
            sh 'mvn -B'
        }
    }
}
```

And give me this error:

```
[Pipeline] withDockerContainer
Jenkins does not seem to be running inside a container 
[Pipeline] // withDockerContainer
```

I don't know why is it stopping like that without doing anything.

I have already install docker, docker plugin/docker pipeline on the latest version.

In configuration tool, i add the installation root path.

Did I miss something ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: you're problem is jenkins not docker. Is the process running?

Comment: Docker is running and Jenkins too, which process do you think about?

Comment: you are saying that your error is Jenkins does not seem to be running inside a container so I was thinking the process might be running

Comment: @flopic I'm experiencing the same issue, did you ever solve this issue?

Answer (score 25):

This message is a normal debug message, maybe a little confusing, but not an error.   As the Jenkins Pipeline code is written, during initialization it checks whether the step is already running in a container.  I think the message could be written better.

If you have more problems than this message, please provide the entire log.  Sounds like maybe a node cannot be assigned, or the docker client is not installed, or the docker image cannot be pulled.

Answer (score 5):

The issue is a bit old but I faced a similar situation and I want to share.

I noticed that Jenkins mentions the the cause of the issue at the end of the pipeline logs.

For example in my case, the issue states:

```
java.io.IOException: Failed to run top '0458e2cc8b4e09c53bb89f680026fc8d035d7e608ed0b60912d9a61ebb4fea4d'. Error: Error response from daemon: Container 0458e2cc8b4e09c53bb89f680026fc8d035d7e608ed0b60912d9a61ebb4fea4d is not running
```

When checking the stage where this happened it's similar to the above you mentioned when using `dockerImage.inside()`, the reason in my case is that my Dockefile already defines an `entrypoint` and when using the `inside` feature jenkins gets confused, so to avoid this try overriding the `entrypoint` by passing it as a parameter to the `inside` function as follows:

```
dockerImage.inside("--entrypoint=''") {
     echo "Tests passed"
}
```

Another good way to find the issue is to access your jenkins server ans list the docker containers with `docker ps -a` you may find the build container failed, check the logs then you will get a hint, in my case the logs says `cat: 1: ./entrypoint.sh: not found`.